# Push view animation on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, quartz-core

I am trying to add a push animation while displaying different views in a kind of image slider. Slides are displayed as expected, but there isn't any animation. I am using the following lines of code to create the animation. *(self is a subclass of NSView)*

```
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
[transition setDuration:0.33f];
[transition setType:kCATransitionPush];
[transition setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
[transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];
[self setAnimations:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:transition forKey:@"subviews"]];

[[self animator] replaceSubview:self.displayedSlide with:slideToDisplay];

[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

Any idea of what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to add `[self setWantsLayer:YES];` and now it works.

Comment: It can be set it in Interface Builder, too, depending on one's preferences for doing things code or in IB.